# Stitching multiple text files together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to stitch text files together line by line, given from the command line, in Python 3.0.

There can be **any amount of files** given from the command line.

So for example, say I have pass in three files: pizza.txt, pasta.txt, drinks.txt

---

pizza.txt

```
Margarita 
Pepperoni
Mushroom
```

pasta.txt

```
Spaghetti 
Carbonara 
Lasagna
```

drinks.txt

```
Beer 
Wine 
Soda
```

---

After stitching my files together, in this scenario, the output should be:

```
Margarita   Spaghetti   Beer
Pepperoni   Carbonara   Wine 
Mushroom   Lasagna    Soda
```

**With each item spaced by a tab(\t)**

---

If the files do **not** match in length, then an empty string should be the placeholder ('').

Example, if there was no "Mushroom" in the pizza.txt file:

```
Margarita   Spaghetti   Beer
Pepperoni   Carbonara   Wine 
            Lasagna    Soda
```

---

I'm interested, 
how would you go about achieving this output?

Comment: you can read them all at once, or line by line. but what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Look at `zip` (and `itertools.zip_longest`).

Comment: @appleapple: I've tried creating a new file: 'with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:' The i've used a for loop to iterate through a list of file names, and opened the files one by one: 'for name in file_names: with open(name, 'r') as in_file:' Then i've used readline(), added a tab at the end of each line per file. Then i wrote the line to the new file. Problem being i can't get past the first line with this method.

Comment: @KidConvalescent you should not use `with` here, every time you leave  the block the file is closed, then next iteration you open it again, so you always get first line. **important**: please [edit] your question with your method and contains [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
import itertools

files = ['pizza', 'pasta', 'drinks']

result = []

for f in files:
    with open('{}.txt'.format(f)) as menu:
        result.append([item.strip() for item in menu])

final = list(itertools.izip_longest(*result, fillvalue=''))
```